# Constexpr constructor is not evaluated at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I want to introduce strong types with error checking at compile time. For my chrono type, I noticed literals are silently narrowed when the underlying type changes from `int64_t` to `int32_t`, leading to overflows. So I introduced an explicit check.

However this check is not checked at compile time even for constant parameters, like `delay_t {10s}`, which cannot be represented.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>


struct delay_t {
    std::chrono::duration<int32_t, std::nano> value {};

    constexpr explicit delay_t(std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano> delay) 
        : value {delay} 
    {
        if (value != delay) {
            throw std::runtime_error("delay cannot be represented.");
        }
    };
};

auto foo(delay_t delay) -> void {}

auto main() -> int {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    foo(delay_t {10s});  // here I want a compile time error, 
                         // but I get a runtime error.

    return 0;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kbexhxf5P)

This unfortunately compiles and leads to a runtime error. I verified that the literal `operator"" s` is a `constexpr` and it works using `consteval` in the `delay_t` constructor. I also want to use the type with runtime values, so that's not an option.

How can I tell the compiler above to evaluate constant literals like `time_t {10s}` at compile time? I am using C++20.

Comment: Maybe just don't use an `int32_t` for *nanosecond* precision?

Answer (score 5):

`constexpr` is evaluated at compile time only in constant expression, not depending of argument.

You might split your expression as

```
constexpr delay_t delay{10s}; // Compile time evaluated, so error at compile time
foo(delay);
```

Comment: Thank you Jarod, this is indeed a very simple and direct solution. I posted an alternative, that doesn't require cooperation by the user of the class. I am not sure yet, if I will go with that, as it requires quite some boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it through a `consteval` function.

```
template<typename T>
consteval T force_constexpr(const T& value) noexcept
{
    return value;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
foo(force_constexpr(delay_t {0s}));  // No compile-time error
foo(force_constexpr(delay_t {10s})); // Compile-time error
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, I realized through your example that to have the compile-time check we need a  consteval function. I combined your idea, while providing an alternative constructor. I am not sure with what I will go, but your solution is definitely an interesting one.

Answer (score 0):

To force checks at compile time the construction from the chrono type needs to be **consteval**. There is no way around it.

```cpp
consteval explicit delay_t(duration<int64_t, std::nano> delay)
  : delay_t {wrapped_{delay}} {};
```

To allow also runtime construction we needs an alternative way to construct `delay_t`. We can for example use a **static method that is constexpr**.

```cpp
constexpr static auto runtime(duration<int64_t, std::nano> delay) -> delay_t {
    return delay_t {wrapped_ {delay}};
}
```

As this method needs to construct `delay_`t in some different way, we need a second non-consteval constructor. But as we already have one for chrono, we need to introduce a private **wrapper type**:

```cpp
private:

struct wrapped_ {
    duration<int64_t, std::nano> value;
};

constexpr delay_t(wrapped_ delay) : value {delay.value} {
    if (value != delay.value) {
        throw std::runtime_error("delay cannot be represented.");
    }
};
```

Using `delay_t` now enforces compile-time checks by default:

```cpp
foo(delay_t {1s});
foo(delay_t {10s});          // gives compile time error
foo(delay_t::runtime(10s));  // gives a runtime error
```

[Full example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MMb3voPP1)